# Delete object with user password - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form_for that will accept the current_users password in order to delete one of their projects. Basically the process of deletion doesn't need to know anything about that user. just the confirmation step of ensuring that they intend to delete the project. What should my form look like? It doesn't have to be form_for it can be form_tag too.

Current View:

```
    <div class="modal">

  <h2>Confirm Project Deletion</h2>

  <%= form_for @user, url: new_account_path, method: :delete, do |f| %>

    <%= f.submit %>

    <% end %>

  </div>
```

I also have access to `@project` which has the current_project attached to it as well as current_user as you can see. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using an authorisation gem such as CanCanCan which would enable resource based authorisation based on current_user - i.e. you can set an ability that enables the current_user to delete projects that only they own? Or is this considered overkill for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly common approach would be to use a delete tag on the index page of all projects, like this:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= project.title %>
  ...
  <% if current_user.id == project.user_id %> 
    <%= link_to project,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'This will delete this project.' } do %> 
  Delete!
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If only the project user can view only his projects on the index page, then just use the link_to method: :delete because the user is already authenticated.

Comment: This isn't very secure though ... there is nothing to stop a malicious user from modifying the page using a random project id and causing havoc by deleting other users projects. You do need some authorisation server side, whether it's user confirmation of authentication details or resource based authorisation on top of authentication.

Comment: current_user become available only after the user is logged in. If the page does not require a current_user, there is no delete button. How is that unsafe?

Comment: user logs in ... views their projects - each with a delete button (because he owns them) .... inspect element in any browser ... modify html to change project id for the delete link ... click submit ... voila ... a project he doesn't have access to can be deleted.

Comment: Just to be clear... I do believe that your answer is a valid one for the question asked. Simply adding a password field only provides limited protection against a hijacked session - it doesn't prevent a user themselves from carrying out malicious actions. I just thought it was worth pointing out, but in hindsight I have gone beyond the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks David; I did not know a user could hack in through the view source in that way. I mean I know how to view source, but I didn't think modifying it on my browser could delete the object. There must be a better way, without requiring a logged-in user to enter a password. Maybe a uuid? Encryption?

Comment: Certainly obfuscation is a good method of protection. Another is to use authorisation (not to be confused with authentication), where you check server side whether the action requested is allowed for the given resource - a gem such as CanCanCan for example allows authorisation of actions on resources which can be scoped by criteria through the use of abilities - for example you can allow users to delete projects but only ones which they own - the ability in this case might look something like `can :delete, Project, user_id: @user.id` where `user_id` is an attribute of Project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a local variable `project` in your page and have a route such as:

`project DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)             projects#destroy`

then you can simply set up a form such as

```
<%= form_tag project_path(id: project.id), method: :delete do %>
  <%= label_tag :password %>
  <%= password_field_tag 'password', '' %>
  <input value='Delete Project' type='submit' id='submit-form'/>
<% end %>
```

All you then need to do is add your authentication check in to the destroy method:

```
def destroy
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  password = params[:password]
  # Do my authentication check here

  if @project and authenticated
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end
end
```

Personally though, I think it would be much better if you implemented a resource based authorisation mechanism, such as CanCanCan, which would work alongside your authentication system. This would enable you to set abilities (rules) that would ensure that the current_user can only view / delete / manage their own projects, without requiring them to authenticate every time they wish to destroy a resource.